# How do I create a random string of 4 numbers which does not exist already in my list in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, list, lookup

This is the code I use currently. The function `createRandomNumberString` returns a string of 4 numbers. I run this function as long as it returns a string which I already have inside `this.usernameIds`

```
while (this.usernameIds.includes(randomString)) {
    randomString = createRandomNumberString();
}
this.usernameIds.push(randomString);
```

The problem I have with this code is that it might run indefinitely and want to avoid this of happening. How could this piece of code be rewritten?

(I already check beforehand that `this.usernameIds`'s length is less than 10,000.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of loops too:

```
let maxLoop = 10;
do
{
    randomString = createRandomNumberString();
}
while(this.usernameIds.includes(randomString) && --maxLoop);

if (maxLoop)
  this.usernameIds.push(randomString);
```

Comment: Before I tried a thousand times to create a non-existing string, but this would be a bad practice.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean. What is your question? Improve your code so it doesn't infinite loop or a function that generates random strings? Since you didn't show your random string generator function I'd assume you question is about avoid infinite loop, hens is this answer. Also, any reason why you are storing numbers as strings?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not concerned about memory consumption you may just use `source` array of all available identifiers and select from it:

```js
const availableIds = Array.from({ length: 10000 }, (_, i) => i)
const usernameIds = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (!availableIds.length) break;
  
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableIds.length)
  const [id] = availableIds.splice(rnd, 1)
  const strId = String(id).padStart(4, '0')
  
  usernameIds.push(strId)
}

console.log(usernameIds)
```

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is removing 1 element of the `source` array on each cycle so your ids will always be unique. Untill you run out of them. Then the `for` loop just breaks to the outer code;

Comment: This would create an array with a massive length which would be bad for my server.